# How to add dedendency in SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new `scala` and `SBT`. I am trying write a pursuing engine which can read the `JSON` `string` to `object` and write back `Object` to `JSON string`. To do that I am using `eclipse` as `IDE` and `SBT(0.13.13)` as build tool and `jackson`. I am getting some error while trying to import the dependency in scala file. My steps as follows:

1. I have added this two `dependency` in `build.sbt` of my project

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.5.3"
   libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.8"
   ```
2. Compile the project from `SBT` console with "compile" command
3. Creating a `scala` object for `DAO` object, which will contain the data and transfer as `JSON`

But when I am trying to import this in scala source file:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
```

It's giving some compilation error:

> object fasterxml is not a member of package com

But my compilation, which I did to download those dependency, ends up with success and showing download as `[SUCCESSFUL]`

I think I am missing something, can any one help me out in this regard?

As part of experiment I have added MySql dependency in my project as:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.40"
```

Which is working properly, I am able to connect the MySql Server from scala code.

One more thing as in `Maven` we can update or if we save the POM file, `maven` downloads all those dependency automatically. Is that the same in `SBT` or every time after adding dependency in `build.sbt` I have to "reload" and "compile" to download?

Comment: did you remember to run `reload` at step 2.

Comment: 1) make sure dependencies are available `sbt "inspect tree clean" | grep jackson ` 2) make sure imported classes belong to dependencies. 3) Try synchronizing the sbt dependencies in eclipse. if you are using mvn-eclipse plugin `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` otherwise, something like `File -> Refresh`

Comment: @stephen , I use reload

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the steps you need to follow
1) clean your project in eclipse (eclipse might cache dependencies)
2) make sure your project directories are as explained in [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html)
3) If above two steps doesn't work do

```
import _root_.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import _root_.com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import _root_.com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
```

Hope you get it solved